# Fetching the first date of a week in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, simpledateformat

I would like to fetch the first date of a week.

My input is going to be a String type like 07/26/2014".

I need to get the first date of week in which the above date(07/26/2014) falls.

I need output  date in MM/dd/YYYY format .

basically I need output as 07/21/2014.

Please give me the  java program. I have done upto this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
String date ="07/26/2014";
    Date Currentdate = formatter1.parse(date);
    int currentday=Currentdate.getDay();


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(Currentdate);
        int startDay=currentday-calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek();
        Currentdate.setDate(contacteddate.getDate()-startDay);
        System.out.println(contacteddate.getDate());
    }
```

The above code only gives me the date.. I need date along with month and year in "MM/dd/YYYY"
Please help

Comment: As this is not an Android question, it us not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: And a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10119782/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2109145/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2937086/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15503105/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14521539/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9307884/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4536230/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21370386/642706) and [more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Java+date+first+of+week).

Answer (score 5):

I would do it this way

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(Currentdate);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

Comment: Note that this depends on *what* the first day according to the given locale is. For someone in the US the answer for `07/26/2014` will be the 20th and not the 21st. Just something to take into account.

Answer (score 4):

After setting time to [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(Currentdate);
```

use

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
```

and then

```
simpleFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: I think OP wants MONDAY, not SUNDAY = 1. Your code yields one day earlier in US.

Comment: @Meno first day of week depends on Locale you set

Comment: Yes I know, the first day of week is dependent on the Locale. But maybe I was not quite clear. I referred to the line `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)`. The number 1 stands for the constant `Calendar.SUNDAY`. And the OP wants "07/21/2014" which is a Monday.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

```
 // Get calendar set to current date and time
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

 // Set the calendar to monday of the current week
 c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

 // Print dates of the current week starting on Monday
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM/yyyy");
 for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
   System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
   c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**The problem with all presented solutions so far is not to specify what exactly the week definition is.** Week definitions are either technically specified like in ISO-8601-standard (Monday as first day of week and first calendar week of year containing at least four days), or they use localized rules (for example in US a week begins by Sunday!).

Due to the requirement that the OP wants "07/21/2014" as first day of week around "07/26/2014" it seems that ISO-8601 is what the OP really wants. But code like

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
...
```

will not work in a country like US or an application server located in US. Counter example:

```
// simulating a US-located application server where this code is running
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.US);

calendar.set(2014, Calendar.JULY, 26);
calendar.getTime(); // avoid ugly side effects in calendar date handling
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime())); // output: 2014-07-20
```

If the OP changes the choosen locale to let's say `Locale.FRANCE` (applying ISO-rules) then the OP can achieve his goal using the traditional Java-date-and-time-library.

**It should be noted however that week handling using the `java.util.Calendar`-stuff is often confusing and hard.** For example: Without the strange getter-call (`calendar.getTime()`) which enforces update of internal calculation the result would be: 2014-07-06 (surely not what OP wants).

Therefore I recommend following other libraries to choose a generic approach compatible with different week definitions:

**a) [Java-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) (built-in library JSR-310 aka java.time):**

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2014, 7, 26);
TemporalField dowField = WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek();
date = date.with(dowField, dowField.range().getMinimum());
System.out.println(date); // output: 2014-07-21
```

Note: Avoid code like date.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY) because in that case the java.time-library cannot evaluate the underlying week rules which possibly deviate from ISO-8601 (here choosen: `WeekFields.ISO`, but it might also be `WeekFields.SUNDAY_START`).

**b) my own library [Time4J](http://github.com/MenoData/time4j/releases):**

```
PlainDate date = PlainDate.of(2014, 7, 26);
date = date.with(Weekmodel.ISO.localDayOfWeek().minimized());
System.out.println(date); // output: 2014-07-21
```

**c) If you know in advance that you only want ISO-8601-week-rules then you might also consider a simpler approach in Java-8 or instead its predecessor [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.Property.html#withMinimumValue()):**

```
// Java-8 applying ISO-8601-rules
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2014, 7, 26);
date = date.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);

// Joda-Time
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2014, 7, 26);
date = date.dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue();
```